# Already implemented neural network on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have implemented a neural network model using Python and Tensorflow, which normally runs on my own computer. 
Now I would like to train it on new datasets on the Google Cloud Platform. Do you think it is possible? Do I need to change my code?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes. And probably. Without more detailed information, that is the only answer I can give you.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't. Here is a detailed introduction how to launch a compute engine and install TensorFlow in GCP: https://hackernoon.com/launch-a-gpu-backed-google-compute-engine-instance-and-setup-tensorflow-keras-and-jupyter-902369ed5272

Comment: To train a model in  GCP ML Engine, just write your algorithm in TensorFlow Estimator API (or) create a custom estimator, submit a job in ML Engine. [https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/training-overview] refer this link. I think it will get you a overall idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud offers the [Cloud ML Engine](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/) service, which allows to train your models and perform predictions without the need of running and maintaining an instance with the required software.

In order to run the TensorFlow NN models you already have, you will not need to change your code, you will only have to package the trainer appropriately, as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-steps), and run a ML Engine job that performs the training itself. Once you have your model, you can also [deploy](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/deploying-models) it in the same service and later get predictions with different features depending on your requirements (urgency in getting the predictions, data set sources, etc.).

Alternatively, as suggested in the comments, you can always launch a Compute Engine instance and run there your TensorFlow model as if you were doing it locally in your computer. However, I would strongly recommend the approach I proposed earlier, as you will be saving some money, because you will only be [charged for your usage](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/pricing) (training jobs and/or predictions) and do not need to configure an instance from scratch.